# chromedriver with selenium gird - No such file or directory

Tags: python, linux, selenium, selenium-grid, selenium-chromedriver

I'm having trouble running chrome instances on a grid I've set up

I get the following error:

```
ERROR [21] org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess - org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException:
Execution failed (Exit value: -559038737. Caused by java.io.IOException: Cannot run program
"/tmp/webdriver/chromedriver/chromedriver_2.13_32bit" (in directory "."): error=2, No such
file or directory)
```

I assure you that `/tmp/webdriver/chromedriver/chromedriver_2.13_32bit` exists its also executable (chmod +x)

The arguments I ran the node with:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar -port 5555 -role node -hub http://10.20.102.176:4444/grid/register -nodeConfig /opt/selenium/node_5555.json -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/tmp/webdriver/chromedriver/chromedriver_2.13_32bit
```

Even made `symlink` to the default places where the selenium goes if path to the driver is not supplied

`/usr/local/bin/chromedriver`
`/usr/bin/chromedriver`

but still I get the same error when I try to run something.

---

Extra information - maybe it will help:

I've also tried running chrome instance from python on that machine

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome

a = Chrome('/tmp/webdriver/chromedriver/chromedriver_2.13_32bit')
```

the traceback i get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'path'
>>> a = Chrome('/tmp/webdriver/chromedriver/chromedriver_2.13_32bit')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 59, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/service.py", line 66, in start
    "ChromeDriver executable needs to be available in the path. "
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: ChromeDriver executable needs to be available in the path. Please download from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html and read up at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver
```

I asked for help at [chromedriver-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromedriver-users/hAEhyK-63Gc) Google group, but got no response there.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that, I was trying to run 32bit bin file in a 64bit system.

there are two solutions:

my server was missing `ia32-lib` - it turns out, you can't just run 32bit in a 64bit system
all i had to do is: `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs` to add support for 32bit

Or

Just download and use the 64bit Chromedriver